# How to remove a space when the user clicks on a menu item

Tags: css

I'm creating an HTML/CSS menu for an Angular project.
I have two rubrics in the menu...

[image]

When I click on a rubric, there is a space that is created, how could I solve this problem, please?

The problem happens when hovering...

[image]

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #f5f6fa;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 225px;
  background: rgb(5, 68, 104);
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 13px 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  color: rgb(241, 237, 237);
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .icon {
  color: #dee4ec;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #0c7db1;
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(5, 68, 104);
}

.wrapper .sidebar li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 1rem;
  left: auto;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.wrapper .sidebar li.active .menu {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li.active i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Top Menu -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <!-- Menu Item -->
    <ul>
      <li
        *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index"
        [class.active]="menu.active"
      >
        <ng-container>
          <a class="item" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
            <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </a>
        </ng-container>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I share you a reproduction on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ft3cs?file=src/styles.css).

Thank you in advance for your help and sharing.

Comment: Seems like border-right on hover is the issue => .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover { color: #0c7db1; }
```

Just Remove the border tag From Hover and it will fix your Problem

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggests,

> Seems like border-right on hover is the issue => `.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover`
> @emre-ozgun

I have commented that line, see the answer snippet below

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #f5f6fa;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 225px;
  background: rgb(5, 68, 104);
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 13px 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  color: rgb(241, 237, 237);
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .icon {
  color: #dee4ec;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #0c7db1;
 /* border-right: 2px solid rgb(5, 68, 104);*/
}

.wrapper .sidebar li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 1rem;
  left: auto;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.wrapper .sidebar li.active .menu {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li.active i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Top Menu -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <!-- Menu Item -->
    <ul>
      <li
        *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index"
        [class.active]="menu.active"
      >
        <ng-container>
          <a class="item" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
            <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </a>
        </ng-container>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```